# I have python code for decode AIS data and display it on the map real time

Tags: python, python-3.x, folium, ais

I work in project for my university, the project is to develop a map using python and add AIS live data and display the ships on the map. I created the map and I make code for decode the AIS data but still I can't display the live tracking of the ship on the map.So I face issue in visualisation the ship's data on the map.

this is the code

`import sys import serial import folium from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QVBoxLayout from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView from PyQt5.QtCore import QTimer`

```
class MapWidget(QWidget):
def init(self, parent=None):
super(MapWidget, self).__init__(parent)
```

```
# Create a Folium map object
self.msc_map = folium.Map(location=[23.631234255986154, 58.26947439827522], zoom_start=15)
```

```
# Create a QWebEngineView object to display the map
self.webview = QWebEngineView()
self.webview.setHtml(self.msc_map.get_root().render())
```

```
# Create a layout and add the webview to it
layout = QVBoxLayout(self)
layout.addWidget(self.webview)
```

```
# Set up AIS data processing
self.serial_port = serial.Serial("COM3", 38400) # Adjust baud rate as needed
self.timer = QTimer(self)
self.timer.timeout.connect(self.update_data)
self.timer.start(1000) # Adjust the interval as needed
```

```
def update_data(self):
if self.serial_port.isOpen():
data = self.serial_port.readline().decode('utf-8')
self.decode_and_update_map(data)
```

```
def decode_and_update_map(self, data):
try:
# Assuming the data format is "!AIVDM,1,1,,A,...."
if "!AIVDM" in data:
parts = data.split(',')
if len(parts) >= 8 and parts[5] in ('A', 'B') and parts[7] in ('A', 'B'):
latitude = self.extract_coordinate(parts[6])
longitude = self.extract_coordinate(parts[8])
```

```
# Add a play icon marker to the map
folium.Marker(
location=[latitude, longitude],
icon=folium.Icon(color='blue', icon='play')
).add_to(self.msc_map)
```

```
# Save the updated map to HTML
self.msc_map.save('AIS_Map.html')
```

```
# Reload the web view to reflect the changes
self.webview.setHtml(self.msc_map.get_root().render())
```

```
except ValueError as e:
print(f"Error parsing latitude and longitude: {e}")
```

```
def extract_coordinate(self, coordinate_part):
degrees = float(coordinate_part[:2])
minutes = float(coordinate_part[2:])
decimal_degrees = degrees + minutes / 60.0
return decimal_degrees
```

```
def closeEvent(self, event):
self.timer.stop()
self.serial_port.close()
event.accept()
```

```
if name == '__main__':
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
widget = MapWidget()
widget.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Fix the code and let me know the issu

Comment: Welcome to [so]. We don't provide generalized debugging services. We can assist with specific issues. Please use the following references on debugging your code to narrow your problem to a specific issue. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), [Six Debugging Techniques for Python Programmers](https://medium.com/techtofreedom/six-debugging-techniques-for-python-programmers-cb25a4baaf4b)  or [Ultimate Guide to Python Debugging](https://towardsdatascience.com/ultimate-guide-to-python-debugging-854dea731e1b)